# Как завершить процесс выполнения пакетного файла, после завершения работы python?

Tags: python, cmd, bat

Имеется код на python. Располагается в папке `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\MyFolder\PythonCode.py`
Код вызывается путем запуска командной строки и ввода в нее команды `startmycode`

То есть, в папке `C:\Windows\System32` находится файл `startmycode.bat`, вызываемый при вводе "команды".

`startmycode.bat` запускает `PythonCode.py`

`PythonCode.py` ждет нажатия клавиши "alt", после чего выводит надпись "Готово" и завершается. Но при этом окно командной строки у меня остается, несмотря на то, что в `startmycode.bat` прописано `exit`.

**PythonCode.py**

```
import os
import keyboard
import sys

def func(event):
    print('Готово')
    sys.exit()  

keyboard.on_press_key('alt', func)
keyboard.wait()
```

**startmycode.bat**

```
@echo off
python "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\MyFolder\PythonCode.py"
exit
```

**Как сделать так, чтобы после нажатия ALT закрывалось окно CMD?** В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: Используйте [`quit()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19747456/12303413)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import os
import keyboard
import sys

def func(event):
    print('Готово')

keyboard.on_press_key('alt', func)
keyboard.wait('alt')
```